# Program not recognizing recently-added column

Tags: vb.net, dataset

Many months after the original table was created, I needed to add an additional Column (CB_NRP_Department) . When I try to run the program, the new column is not recognized. See the below PopulateForm Procedure below to show error.

I’m getting an Exception error

> Column ‘CB_NRP_Department’ does not belong to table Tbl_New_Employee_Database.

I even deleted the “xsd” New_EmployeesDataSet.xsd from the solution explorer and then recreated a new Data source. I get the same error. What do I need to do to make the program recognize the new column? What am I missing?

I've checked for spelling errors, checked the Data Source for the existing column, verified that the new column was in fact in the Table and spelled correctly. I check the Properties of the ComboBox to check for syntax errors. All looks good. A Similar ComboBox works perfectly.

Since I changed the location of the original Table from local "C" drive to a Network drive, I also double clicked on "My Project" to view the Settings. The settings also look correct:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\nfmfile01\is_db\new_employees\New_Employees.mdb
```

Since I thought that the program was looking at the wrong table, I also renamed all the local "C" drive "New_Employees.mdb" to "New_Employees_OLD.mdb.

```
If Not IsDBNull(ds.Tables("Tbl_New_Employees_Database").Rows(inc).Item("Dt_NRP_DOB")) Then
    Frm_New_Resident_Physicians.Dt_NRP_DOB.Value = ds.Tables("Tbl_New_Employees_Database").Rows(inc).Item("Dt_NRP_DOB")
End If

If ds.Tables.Contains("CB_NRP_Department") Then
    MsgBox("Yep, it's there")
Else
    MsgBox("Nop, Not there!!") '<- I get the Nop, Not there!!
End If
```

For the next line of code, I get the error message:

> SystemArgumentException: 'Column 'CB_NRP_Department' does not belong to table Tbl_New_Employees_Database.

```
If Not IsDBNull(ds.Tables("Tbl_New_Employees_Database").Rows(inc).Item("CB_NRP_Department")) Then
    Frm_New_Resident_Physicians.CB_NRP_Department.Text = ds.Tables("Tbl_New_Employees_Database").Rows(inc).Item("CB_NRP_Department")
End If

If Not IsDBNull(ds.Tables("Tbl_New_Employees_Database").Rows(inc).Item("Rad_NRP_Needs_Cerner_Credentials_Yes")) Then Frm_New_Resident_Physicians.Rad_NRP_Needs_Cerner_Credentials_Yes.Checked = ds.Tables("Tbl_New_Employees_Database").Rows(inc).Item("Rad_NRP_Needs_Cerner_Credentials_Yes")
If Not IsDBNull(ds.Tables("Tbl_New_Employees_Database").Rows(inc).Item("Rad_NRP_Needs_Cerner_Credentials_No")) Then Frm_New_Resident_Physicians.Rad_NRP_Needs_Cerner_Credentials_No.Checked = ds.Tables("Tbl_New_Employees_Database").Rows(inc).Item("Rad_NRP_Needs_Cerner_Credentials_No")

If Not IsDBNull(ds.Tables("Tbl_New_Employees_Database").Rows(inc).Item("CB_NRP_Person_to_Model_After")) Then
        Frm_New_Resident_Physicians.CB_NRP_Person_to_Model_After.Text = ds.Tables("Tbl_New_Employees_Database").Rows(inc).Item("CB_NRP_Person_to_Model_After")
End If
```

Comment: If you have a typed DataSet then why is all your code written for an untyped DataSet?  Learn how to use a typed DataSet.  The DataSet itself has a property for each DataTable, you index the DataTable itself to get a row and the DataRow has a property for each column.

Comment: As for the issue, if you change the database schema then you need to open the Data Sources window and rerun the wizard using the appropriate button on the tool bar.

Comment: jmcilhinney, As for this issue at hand, without having to redesign the Dataset, I have opened the Data Source window and reran the wizard. Nothing different happens. The column that I added to the table does appears in the “Tbl_New_Employees_Database” window (New_EmployeesDataSet.xsd)  with all the other fields. I still get the same error message. This program was running perfectly prior to me adding the additional column. Please advise.

Comment: Your code is all wrong anyway.  You're treating your typed `DataSet` like it's an untyped `DataSet`.  Use it properly.  You don't use the `Tables` collection of the `DataSet` because it has a property for each `DataTable`. You don't use the `Rows` collection because you index the `DataTable` itself. You don't use the `Item` property of the row because it has a property for each column.  You don't use the `IsDBNull` method either because the row has a method dedicated to checking each column for NULL.

Comment: One of the main reasons to use all those properties - the very purpose of a typed `DataSet` is that you get full Intellisense and compiler support at design time and don't have to wait until run time to find out that you did something wrong.

Comment: Problem resolved - My issue had nothing to do with typed Dataset/untyped Dataset. The issue was the fact that I neglected to add the additional field to my Sql statement of my connection string. (da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter (Sql, cn). All is good again.